# Javascript extends does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, extends

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var animal = {
    type: "mammal"
};

var dog = {
    sound: "bark"
};

dog.extends(animal);
alert(dog.type);
});
</script>
```

The above code is not alerting, and erroring out saying that undefined is not a function. Any idea why?

Comment: object does not have an extend method

Comment: may be http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/t4c46dzz/1/

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var animal = {
        type: "mammal"
    };

    var dog = {
        sound: "bark"
    };

    $.extend(dog, animal);
    alert(dog.type);
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/auekn4f1/

Comment: Yea, this works. Thanks :) But the way i have extended in my code, isn't it another way?